# How to replace string with the value of variable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, csharpcodeprovider

```
if(Node.NodeType.ToString().Equals("Element", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    if(Node.Name.ToString().Equals("DeployWebsite", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Count++;
    }
    string myString = Count.ToString();
    string name = "//"+"website"+"["+ myString+"]"+"/";

    string[] DetailsOfNodesToDisplay = Node.InnerText.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for(int i = 0; i < DetailsOfNodesToDisplay.Count(); i++)
    {
        string addressOfNode = DetailsOfNodesToDisplay[i].Replace('.', '/');
        if(Node.Name.ToString().Equals("DeployWebsite", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            addressOfNode = addressOfNode.Replace("/Website/", "name");
            // string addressOfNode1 = addressOfNode.Replace("/website/", "//website[1]/");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace `"/Website"` with the value of `name` variable.
Name variable is string containing value.

Comment: I have added code snap please look into that

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (in text).

Comment: Please, paste the code in the question instead of a link to a screenshot. Use `addressOfNode.Replace("/Website/", name)`. `"name"` is a string, `name` is a variable

Comment: Note that `"//"+"website"+"["` is also probably not what you intended to write

Answer (score 0):

If you create the string on runtime use string interpolation like

```
string someString = "someText/{name}"; Where "/{name}" was "/Website" before.
```

but if the string is already defined use

```
someString.Replace("/Website", name);
```